# Objective-C on GNUStep: Accessing ivars of the parent class

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, gnustep

I'm pretty new to Objective-C. Most of my experience is in Java. I have a base class:

```
@interface Bug : NSObject <BugProtocol> {

    @private
    World* world;
    NSString* name;
    NSString* layer;
    long x;
    long y;
    BOOL alive;

...
...


}

...
...

@end
```

and a class that extends this base class:

```
@interface RandomBug : Bug
    ...
    ...
@end
```

However, when I try to access properties that I've defined in the parent class, the compiler complains that it cannot find them. Most of the examples I've seen for access properties is tailored towards OS X (i.e., using things like `@property` which, as far as I know, is not fully supported in GNUStep).

Comment: So, how do you declare those properties? Also, it's not GNUstep that supports or doesn't support keywords - it's the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I just need to use `@protected` (just like in Java):

```
@interface Bug : NSObject <BugProtocol> {

    @protected
    World* world;
    NSString* name;
    NSString* layer;
    long x;
    long y;
    BOOL alive;

...
...


}

...
...

@end
```

Comment: Those aren't properties but ivars, huge difference in Objective-C!

Comment: Oops, sorry. What's the difference between the two in Objective-C?